# Change p-inputSwitch label and style

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I would change the style of p-inputSwitch component of Primeng library

I would get something like this:

[image: expected design]

Here's my code :

```
<div class="contner">
    <div class="toggle-area">
        <p>SEARCH BY</p>
        <div >
        <p class ="toggle-inline">Business group</p>
        <div class="toggle-btn toggle-inline">
            <p-inputSwitch [(ngModel)]="checked"
            onLabel=""
            offLabel=""
            styleClass="ui-inputswitch"
            ></p-inputSwitch>
        </div>
        <p class="toggle-inline">Borrower</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

I started by deleting labels but width changes also and I don't know how to increase it

[image: What I have]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I started by deleting labels but width changes also and I don't know how to increase it

Override PrimeNG `ui-inputswitch` class :

```
.ui-inputswitch {
  width: 80px !important;
}
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CvJxrMxnGUgc6bFQHIVj?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

just but the input switch in  a div and adjust this class to your need

```css
      .smaller-switch {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
```

```html
      <div class="smaller-switch">
                                          <p-inputSwitch
                                          [(ngModel)]="country['isBranded']"
                                          (onChange)="setBrandedSettings($event)"
                                          [disabled]="( (templateDetails && templateDetails['type'] == 'Public' && RoleID!=rolesIds.NetworksMainManagers)||  RoleID == rolesIds.Networks) || selectedCriteriaCountry['country']!=country['country']"
                                          id="brandedswitch"></p-inputSwitch>

                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace your div element with following

```
<p-toggleButton onLabel="Business Group(s)" offLabel="Borrower(s)"
    onIcon="fa-toggle-on" offIcon="fa-toggle-off" [(ngModel)]="checked"></p-toggleButton>
```